# Convenção para atributos que preservam tipos

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

Uma tabela armazena dados de *professores*. Cada professor possui uma titulação: especialista, mestre, doutor, pós-doutor e outros.

Outra tabela presente na base é a de *publicações*. Cada publicação pode (ou não) possuir um determinado tipo: livro, periódico, evento, tcc e outros.

É certo que em cada tabela haverá uma coluna (atributo) para manter o *tipo* do determinado registro.

Abaixo, duas sugestões para o valor desses atributos:

1. abreviações (strings)

   professor.tipo = 'mes' || professor.tipo = 'dr' || professor.tipo = 'esp'

   publicacao.tipo = 'liv' || publicacao.tipo = 'tcc' || publicacao.tipo = 'evt'
2. inteiros

   professor.tipo = 1 || professor.tipo = 2 || professor.tipo = 3

   publicacao.tipo = 1 || publicacao.tipo = 2 || publicacao.tipo = 3

Minha questão é: **existe alguma convenção para esses atributos** ou a decisão é de responsabilidade do(s) desenvolvedor(es) do projeto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Existe as regras normais para normalização de banco de dados:

- **Primeira Forma Normal (ou 1FN)** requer que todos os valores de colunas em uma tabela sejam atômicos (exemplo: um número é um átomo, enquanto uma lista ou um conjunto não o são). A normalização para a primeira forma normal elimina grupos repetidos, pondo-os cada um em uma tabela separada, conectando-os com uma chave primária ou estrangeira;
- **Segunda Forma Normal (ou 2FN)** requer que não haja dependência funcional não-trivial de um atributo que não seja a chave, em parte da chave candidata;
- **Terceira Forma Normal (ou 3FN)** requer não haver dependências funcionais não-triviais de atributos que não sejam chave, em qualquer coisa exceto um superconjunto de uma chave candidata;
  Forma Normal de Boyce-Codd (ou BCNF) requer que não exista nenhuma dependência funcional não-trivial de atributos em algo mais do que um superconjunto de uma chave candidata. Neste estágio, todos os atributos são dependentes de uma chave, de uma chave inteira e de nada mais que uma chave (excluindo dependências triviais, como A → A);
- **Quarta Forma Normal (ou 4FN)** requer que não exista nenhuma dependência multi-valorada não-trivial de conjuntos de atributo em algo mais de que um superconjunto de uma chave candidata;
- **Quinta Forma Normal (ou 5FN ou PJ/NF)** requer que não exista dependências de joins (associações) não triviais que não venham de restrições chave;
- **Domain-Key Normal Form (ou DK/NF)** requer que todas as restrições sigam os domínios e restrições chave.

> Respondendo ao seu problema especifico:

```
CREATE TABLE titulo (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE professor (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    titulo_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY titulo_key (titulo_id) REFERENCES titulo(id)
);
```

Fonte para regras normais: [Link](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados)